# Django base.html serving static sheets

Tags: html, django

I need some direction-currently depolying my app on a local django development server.

my base.html file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<div style="width:50%; marginleft:25%;"> 


</div>
```

I am only seeing the bullet pointed contents of my base.html with no styling-should I just reference a css sheet to get see an actual webpage layout?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain more what you're trying to achieve, and what styling you expect to see?

Comment: I just want to see a basic webpage with div's so I can use this as a framework for my app. I am now getting a 'template syntax error' whilst template rendering-I belive the issue is in the views.py file: # Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('base.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    

def results(request):
    return render_to_response('admigo/results.html')

Comment: Python is a language where spaces and indentation are important. You can't post an entire file in a comment. A `TemplateSytaxError` means, unsurprisingly, that there is an *error in your template* (not your view). Either way, Django didn't just say `TemplateSyntaxError`, there was a full stack trace which tells you what the problem was. Either look at it or post it. Finally, it sounds like your main problem is that you're unfamiliar with Django, HTML and CSS (no offence intended; everyone starts somewhere). Perhaps go through basic tutorials for each before posting specific problems here.

Comment: For people here to be able to help you, we also need to understand exactly what you're trying to do, and what the problem is. If your `base.html` looks exactly like you've posted then I have **no idea** what you're trying to do — it's an empty (and invalid) HTML page, describing a `div` that takes up 50% of the width. The margin will be unchanged as it should be `margin-left`.

Comment: You need to address the fact that your question says "the bullet pointed contents" when your posted `base.html` *has no content*. Once you've got content, to style it you just specify style rules — in a `<style>` tag, in a CSS file or inline. There's nothing Django-specific about this, except for serving static files, which is [explained in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

Answer (score 0):

if that is the only styling on your site then you need to create styles, the best way to do this is through a css file.  If you already have a css file with styles then you can reference it in your base template so all children templates load the styles.

You need to set up your project to [serve static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) files in development.

`<link href="/static/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Your type is invalid in the example that you posted.

Comment: Though I am still only seeing the contents even if I reference my CSS-am I missing something in the urls.py file:                                                                       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "XHTML1-s.dtd" ><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title> 

</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="" /> 

<meta name="description" content="" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"

type="/text/css"/>

</head>

<body> 


</body></html>

Comment: Yes-I noticed that too-still the issue exists-I have posted how my views.py file looks above-is it something to do with serving static files that I am missing?

Comment: @user1508851: PLEASE, for the love of all that is good and holy in the world, update your question with code samples. *Don't* post them as comments.